# Notebook widgets do not display properly unless we resize the window in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

im having a little issue with NoteBook switching. When I switch notebook tabs, I will need to resize to make the wigdets display properly. I tried using self.Refresh() but that does not seem to do anything. If you have trouble understanding me, please run the following code, then switch tabs and resize, you will notice that there is problems, displaying things correctly. I do not know if this is a problem with wxPython but I think it is with my code.

```
IMAGE_NAME = []
IMAGE_DATA = []
IMAGEMORE_NAME=[]
IMAGEMORE_DATA=[]

import sys
import wx

def deletepic(self):
    try:
        self.parent.bitmap.Destroy()
    except:
        print sys.exc_info()

def sendnewpic(self):
    if self.parent.bitmap: deletepic(self)  
    if IMAGE_DATA[self.image_listsel] != '':
        try:
            print IMAGE_DATA[self.image_listsel]
            bmp = wx.Image(IMAGE_DATA[self.image_listsel], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
            self.parent.scroll_img.SetScrollbars(1, 1, bmp.GetWidth(), bmp.GetHeight())
            self.parent.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.parent.scroll_img, -1, bmp, (0, 0))
            self.parent.Refresh()
        except:
            pass

def areachange(self, pg):
    print pg
    try:
        if IMAGE_DATA[self.image_listsel] == '':
            deletepic(self)
    except:
        pass

    if pg == "Regular Pictures":
        self.images_area.Show()
        self.scroll_img.Show()
        self.btnTwo.Show()
    else:
        self.images_area.Hide()
        self.scroll_img.Hide()
        self.btnTwo.Hide()
    if pg == "More Pictures":
        self.images_area.Show()
        self.scroll_img.Show()
        self.imageboxersiz.Show()
    else:
        self.imageboxersiz.Hide()
    self.Refresh()



class imageTab(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, grandparent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = grandparent
        self.image_listsel = 0
        self.listBox = wx.ListBox(self, size=(200, -1), choices=IMAGE_NAME, style=wx.LB_SINGLE)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) #change to horizontal for side by side
        self.sizerMain = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.listBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK, self.reName)
        self.listBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.imagesel)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Create New",size=(200, 40))
        btnTwo = wx.Button(self, label="Test 2",size=(200, 40))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newAddImage)
        self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=1, flag=wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT, border=5)
        btnSizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        btnSizer.Add(btnTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(btnSizer)
        self.sizerMain.Add(self.sizer, proportion=0, flag=wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND, border=0)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerMain)

    def imagesel(self, evt):
        self.image_listsel = self.listBox.GetSelection()
        sendnewpic(self)

    def newAddImage(self, evt):
        IMAGE_NAME.append('hi')
        IMAGE_DATA.append('')
        self.listBox.Set(IMAGE_NAME)
        self.listBox.SetSelection(len(IMAGE_NAME)-1)
        self.imagesel(None) #making it a selected image, globally

    def reName(self,parent):
        sel = self.listBox.GetSelection()
        text = self.listBox.GetString(sel)
        renamed = wx.GetTextFromUser('Rename item', 'Rename dialog', text)
        if renamed != '':
            IMAGE_NAME.pop(sel)
            IMAGE_NAME.insert(sel,renamed)
            self.listBox.Set(IMAGE_NAME)
            self.listBox.SetSelection(sel)

class objectTab(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, grandparent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = grandparent
        self.image_listsel = 0
        self.listBox = wx.ListBox(self, size=(200, -1), choices=IMAGEMORE_NAME, style=wx.LB_SINGLE)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) #change to horizontal for side by side
        self.sizerMain = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.listBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK, self.reName)
        self.listBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.imagesel)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Create New",size=(200, 40))
        btnTwo = wx.Button(self, label="Test 2",size=(200, 40))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newAddImage)
        self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=1, flag=wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT, border=5)
        btnSizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        btnSizer.Add(btnTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(btnSizer)
        self.sizerMain.Add(self.sizer, proportion=0, flag=wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND, border=0)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerMain)

    def imagesel(self, evt):
        self.image_listsel = self.listBox.GetSelection()

    def newAddImage(self, evt):
        IMAGEMORE_NAME.append('New image')
        IMAGEMORE_DATA.append('')
        self.listBox.Set(IMAGEMORE_NAME)
        self.listBox.SetSelection(len(IMAGEMORE_NAME)-1)
        self.imagesel(None) #making it a selected image, globally

    def reName(self,parent):
        sel = self.listBox.GetSelection()
        text = self.listBox.GetString(sel)
        renamed = wx.GetTextFromUser('Rename item', 'Rename dialog', text)
        if renamed != '':
            IMAGEMORE_NAME.pop(sel)
            IMAGEMORE_NAME.insert(sel,renamed)
            self.listBox.Set(IMAGEMORE_NAME)
            self.listBox.SetSelection(sel)


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.notebook = wx.Notebook(self, size=(225, -1))
        self.tab_images = imageTab(self.notebook, self)
        self.notebook.AddPage(self.tab_images, "Regular Pictures", select=True)

        self.tab_imagesmore = objectTab(self.notebook, self)
        self.notebook.AddPage(self.tab_imagesmore, "More Pictures")

        self.scroll_img = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)
        self.scroll_img.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 600, 400)

        self.images_area = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, '')
        self.sizerBox = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.images_area, wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.sizerBox2 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizerBox.Add(self.scroll_img, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        self.sizerBox2.Add(self.sizerBox, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.notebook, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) #change to horizontal for side by side
        self.btnTwo = wx.Button(self, label="Load File", size=(200, 40))
        self.bmp = None
        self.bitmap = None
        self.imageboxersiz=wx.ComboBox(self, -1, "None Selected!",(0, 0), (190,20),IMAGE_NAME, wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        btnSizer.Add(self.imageboxersiz, 0, wx.TOP, 15)
        btnSizer.Add(self.btnTwo, 0, wx.TOP, 15)

        self.sizerBox2.Add(btnSizer)
        #
        self.sizer.Add(self.sizerBox2, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.notebook.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.OnPageChanged)
        areachange(self, self.notebook.GetPageText(0))

    def OnClickTop(self, event):
        self.scroll_img.Scroll(600, 400)

    def OnClickBottom(self, event):
        self.scroll_img.Scroll(1, 1)

    def OnPageChanged(self, event):
        new = event.GetSelection()
        areachange(self, self.notebook.GetPageText(new))
        event.Skip()

    def OnPageChanging(self, event):
        event.Skip()


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None, size=(600, 400))
app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, i thought i would just ease things down a bit for the example

Comment: But then it was not possible to load a figure to test it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the self.Refresh() to self.Layout(). Worked for me on Windows 7 anyway.

Comment: What's the difference between Refresh, Layout and Update?

Comment: Update(self)

Calling this method immediately repaints the invalidated area of the window instead of waiting for the EVT_PAINT event to happen, (normally this would usually only happen when the flow of control returns to the event loop.) Notice that this function doesn't refresh the window and does nothing if the window has been already repainted. Use Refresh first if you want to immediately redraw the window (or some portion of it) unconditionally. - http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#Update

Comment: Layout is usually only needed when you add or remove a widget after showing the application on screen. See also http://wiki.wxpython.org/WhenAndHowToCallLayout